# PayPal dodirectpayment API unique correlation but duplicate transaction ID

Tags: api, paypal

We just came across this problem this past week.

We are sending the API SEPARATE orders/invoice IDs, and it is returning the SAME transaction ID back, and not processing one of the payments. We do not get the payment in our PayPal account, and our response from the API is the SAME transaction ID as the first transaction, even though we are sending a separate order, and we get a separate correlation ID.

We have been processing payments just fine up until August. This is when this problem just started occurring. It happens when we send more than 1 order through the API. The problem seems to occur only when sending more than one transaction ID through the system.

We are using [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment

===============
From one of our developers:

We use this. its LEGACY!

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#wpp
we use this function in particular.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

===============

We have over 25 cases where this is documented and PayPal just seems to "lose" and "not process" the order, resulting in the API sending the same transaction ID back, with a different correlation ID.

We have tried changing our order/inv numbers from having a - (hyphen) to all alphanumeric, we have tried postfixing a random number. None of these seem to work.

The problem does not happen ALL the time. It happens intermittently. Sometimes payments process fine, and other times they do not and only a fraction of the orders are processed correctly, with the others being sent a previous transaction ID.

We spent over 2 hours on the phone at PayPal with someone today. They looked up a sample correlation ID and transaction ID and immediately found something to be wrong on their end.

It is impossible that a unique invoice number be sent to 
PayPal, and then a payment transaction ID be a duplicate returned to us saying successful, but that is what PayPal is returning to us.

I ASK YOU THIS:

How is it possible that we send you an invoice number and you return us a unique correlation ID and a transaction ID and then 47 seconds later we send you a DIFFERENT invoice number and YOU RETURN US THE SAME transaction ID as the invoice 47 seconds earlier?????

SEE HERE

3 orders were made. 1 was fine. 2nd duplicate error we caught, 3rd order fine.

Here is the log..

```
first 3 orders.
<---start paypal send transaction details in function purchase--->
time: 08/20/15 12:10:47 PM
Array
(
    [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [AMT] => 11.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [DESC] =>
    [CREDITCARDTYPE] => visa
    [EXPDATE] => 082017
    [CVV2] => 665
    [IPADDRESS] => xx.xx.xx.xx
    [FIRSTNAME] => xx
    [LASTNAME] => xx
    [STREET] => xx
    [STREET2] =>
    [CITY] => xx
    [STATE] => xx
    [ZIP] => xx
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [INVNUM] => AZ101425x001253x173933x1x761
)


<---end paypal send transaction details in function purchase--->


<---start paypal response transaction details in function purchase--->
time: 08/20/15 12:10:53 PM
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-08-20T19:10:53Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 34d8711050
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [AMT] => 11.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AVSCODE] => Y
    [CVV2MATCH] => M
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 8WS0295W561945T
)


<---end paypal response transaction details in function purchase--->


<---start paypal send transaction details in function purchase--->
time: 08/20/15 12:10:53 PM
Array
(
    [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [AMT] => 11.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [DESC] =>
    [CREDITCARDTYPE] => visa
    [EXPDATE] => 082017
    [CVV2] => 665
    [IPADDRESS] => xx.xx.xx.xx
    [FIRSTNAME] => xx
    [LASTNAME] => xx
    [STREET] => xx 
    [STREET2] =>
    [CITY] => xx
    [STATE] => xx
    [ZIP] => xx
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [INVNUM] => AZ101425x001252x352621x1x579
)


<---end paypal send transaction details in function purchase--->


<---start paypal response transaction details in function purchase--->
time: 08/20/15 12:10:57 PM
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-08-20T19:10:57Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 9abf23471a5
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [AMT] => 11.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AVSCODE] => Y
    [CVV2MATCH] => M
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 8WS0295W561945T
)


<---end paypal response transaction details in function purchase--->


<---start paypal send transaction details in function purchase--->
time: 08/20/15 12:10:57 PM
Array
(
    [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [AMT] => 11.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [DESC] =>
    [CREDITCARDTYPE] => visa
    [EXPDATE] => 082017
    [CVV2] => 665
    [IPADDRESS] => xx.xx.xx.xx
    [FIRSTNAME] => xx
    [LASTNAME] => xx
    [STREET] => xx
    [STREET2] =>
    [CITY] => xx
    [STATE] => xx
    [ZIP] => xx
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [INVNUM] => AZ101425x001252x344289x1x941
)


<---end paypal send transaction details in function purchase--->


<---start paypal response transaction details in function purchase--->
time: 08/20/15 12:11:02 PM
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-08-20T19:11:02Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 4f41a4c7b33
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [AMT] => 11.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AVSCODE] => Y
    [CVV2MATCH] => M
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 9TP856375554029
)


<---end paypal response transaction details in function purchase--->


<---start return values from function multi_payment--->
time: 08/20/15 12:11:02 PM
Array
(
    [photo] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8WS0295W561945T
        )

)


Array
(
    [photo] => Array
        (
            [status] => Error processing payment - Please try again.
        )

)


Array
(
    [photo] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9TP856375554029
        )

)

THEN SHE PAYS AGAIN to get the duplicate..

<---start paypal send transaction details in function purchase--->
time: 08/20/15 12:11:44 PM
Array
(
    [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [AMT] => 11.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [DESC] =>
    [CREDITCARDTYPE] => visa
    [EXPDATE] => 082017
    [CVV2] => 665
    [IPADDRESS] => xx.xx.xx.xx
    [FIRSTNAME] => xx
    [LASTNAME] => xx
    [STREET] => xx
    [STREET2] =>
    [CITY] => xx
    [STATE] => xx
    [ZIP] => xx
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [INVNUM] => AZ101425x001252x352621x1x349
)


<---end paypal send transaction details in function purchase--->


<---start paypal response transaction details in function purchase--->
time: 08/20/15 12:11:49 PM
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-08-20T19:11:49Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 8b30928b03
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [AMT] => 11.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AVSCODE] => Y
    [CVV2MATCH] => M
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 9TP856375554029
)


<---end paypal response transaction details in function purchase--->
```

It’s a duplicate of the 3rd one from first batch she tried above.

HOW IS THAT POSSIBLE?!?!

(FYI Some of the Corrlelation ID and Transaction IDs have been shortened on purpose for security)

Comment: Try passing the variable "MSGSUBID" along with the other variables in your API request  . You can pass "MSGSUBID" as the same value for "INVNUM" and see if that makes each api call unique .

Comment: Check your PayPal profile payment preferences and see if you have selected to block duplicate invoice id's.

Comment: Guys, please read the entire post. We are NOT having duplicate invoice ID's.

Comment: yeah I read the post and therefore suggested to pass that parameter to make the api call's distinguishable ..